# I Trying to solve the "String Score" problem on codeforces

Tags: python, string

I was trying to solve a problem on codeforces this is the link of it: [Link](https://codeforces.com/group/MWSDmqGsZm/contest/219856/problem/R)

> Given a number  and a string  of size  consisting of 5 different
> uppercase characters only {V,W,X,Y,Z}.
>
> - V: Adds to the score 5 points.
> - W: Adds to the score 2 points.
> - X: Removes the next consecutive character from the score.
> - Y: Moves the next consecutive character to the end of the string.
> - Z: If the next consecutive character is V it divides the total score by 5 but if it is W it divides the total score by 2. Then it removes
>   the next consecutive character from the string if and only if the next
>   character is V or W.
>
> **Note**: In case the string ends with X or Y or Z ignore their operations. The score is calculated from left to right and starts with 0.

I Tried this code but unfortunately I get time limit exceeded on test 11
The code:

```
N = int(input())
S = list(input())
C = 0
for i in range(N):
    if i == len(S)-1 and (S[len(S)-1] == "X" or S[len(S)-1] == "Y" or S[len(S)-1] == "Z"):
        break
    if i >= len(S):
        break
        if S[i] == "V" and S[i-1] == "Z":
            C //= 5
    elif S[i] == "V" and (S[i-1] != "X" and S[i-1] != "Z"):
        C += 5
    if S[i] == "W" and S[i-1] == "Z":
        C //= 2
    elif S[i] == "W" and (S[i-1] != "X" and S[i-1] != "Z"):
        C += 2
        if S[i] == "Y":
        S.append(S[i+1])
        del S[i+1]
print(C)
```

Can you help me with that.

Comment: Please put a description of the problem here, not just a link.

Comment: I think the link of the problem is more useful than my description.

Comment: We prefer questions to be self-contained, not dependent on remote sites. You can simply copy and paste the description.

Comment: @Mohamed_Elsharaky that's not the point, your questions here must be self-contained, not dependent on an external site that may disappear at any time

Comment: If you're getting a TLE error, you need to figure out a more efficient algorithm. Coding challenge sites like this generally require you to be more clever than the obvious loop.

Comment: @Barmar Can you suggest a better way for doing that?

Comment: @Barmar I got it in the next time i will attach the description with the problem thank you for your declaration.

Comment: The problem not in the output value it's in the TLE error.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for editing the question.

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is correct? You have an `if` statement after `break`.

Comment: I can't think of a clever solution. It seems like an O(n) problem, so it shouldn't be very slow.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I think their is no way to to make complexity of the problem O(log n) or O(1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really cheating, but I don't know how to describe the optimizations without showing the code.

You can speed up your loop by enumerating through the string instead of trying indexing.  And instead of trying to modify the list in place, just keep track of the added letters and reprocess them later.  Don't try to look ahead, instead remember what the last letter was and use that to affect the current character.  For example:

```
def compute(S):
    C = 0
    while S:
        last = None
        more = []
        for c in S:
            # Handle special actions from the last X, Y, or Z.
            if last == 'X':
                pass
            elif last == 'Y':
                more.append( c )
            elif last == 'Z' and c == 'V':
                C //= 5
            elif last == 'Z' and c == 'W':
                C //= 2
            elif c == 'V':
                C += 5
            elif c == 'W':
                C += 2
            last = c
        S = more
    return C

print(compute('VYWZW'))
print(compute('WZYVXW'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still learning as well, but would like to provide a possible recursive solution here as an alternative. I am not sure how to test for performance, but it seems to get the right output for the test cases above.

Edit: Fixes for index out of bound when string ends in Y, Z.

```
'''
V - Add 5 Points
W - Add 2 Points
X - Remove next character from score
Y - Move next character to end of string
Z - Look at next character. If V, divide score by 5. If W, divide score by 2. If V or W, remove character
'''

def calculate(S, Score=0):
    if type(S) == str:
        S = list(S)
    if len(S) == 0:
        return Score
    if S[0] == "V":
        Score += 5
        return calculate(S[1:], Score)
    if S[0] == "W":
        Score += 2
        return calculate(S[1:], Score)
    if S[0] == "X":
        return calculate(S[2:], Score)
    if S[0] == "Y":
        try:
            next_letter = S[1]
            S = S[2:]
            S.append(next_letter)
            return calculate(S, Score)
        except IndexError:
            return calculate(S[1:], Score)
    if S[0] == "Z":
        try:
            if S[1] == "V":
                Score //= 5
                return calculate(S[2:], Score)
            if S[1] == "W":
                Score //= 2
                return calculate(S[2:], Score)
            if S[1] not in ["V","W"]:
                return calculate(S[1:], Score)
        except IndexError:
            return calculate(S[1:], Score)

print(calculate('VYWZW'))  # 4
print(calculate('WZYVXW'))  # 7
```